# C#: A method that returns true if the value 3 is contained in the array and false otherwise

Tags: c#

I'm trying to translate

"A method that returns true if the value 3 is contained in the array and false otherwise."

into code, but so far the only thing I could come up with is

```
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValueThree();
    }
    static bool ValueThree()
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        if (Array = 3)
    }
    return true;
}
```

Not really sure where do go from here, any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: `static bool ValueThree(int[] arr) => arr.Contains(3);`

Comment: Assuming that this is homework or similar. So without giving away too much... You want to iterate over your collection (the array) and check each element - if it matches, then you return true, else you return false. For bonus points, lookup how to do it elegantly with Linq ;)

Answer (score 0):

An C#-Array implements the `IEnumerable<TSource>` interface. One of the defined methods on this interface is the `Contains(TSource element)` method which checks if the element is in the collection of elements.

So in your case it should be:

```
static bool ValueThree()
{
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
    return arr.Contains(3);
}
```

Comment: `Contains` in this case will actually use the method declared by `IList`, not the extension method `Enumerable.Contains`.

Comment: If you don't want to use LINQ you can replace the last line with - return Array.Contains(arr , 3);

Comment: `IList<T>` actually extends `IEnumerable<T>`. Take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @codran, `IList` is implemented explicitly on `Array`. So only option here is to use `Enumerable.Contains` (the code won't actually compile without `using System.Linq;`)

Comment: Hi, thanks, do you know how I can get this to print out to console? Tried "Console.WriteLine(arr);"

Comment: As I assume you are learning C#, I would suggest you write something like a loop (for or foreach) and write all numbers to the console using `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`. Just search in the internet how to use loops and start from there. You could achieve this by more complex constructs involving LINQ, but I do not recommend this for absolute beginners.